# Is this a concave function?

Tags: convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

Suppose $\gamma \in R^{1}$ and $\beta \in R^{k}$.

Let $f(\gamma,\beta) = (y_{2} - \gamma y_{1}) - (y_{3} - \gamma y_{2}) \exp(x^{\prime}\beta)$.

Then is $f$ a concave function of $(\gamma,\beta^{\prime})$? I just checked its Hessian. It seems the Hessian is negative semi-definite.

Comment: What did you get for the Hessian?

Comment: I don't think it is *ever* the case that a product of independent functions, e.g., $f(x) g(y)$, is convex or concave,  unless $f$ or $g$ is constant.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: $e^{x^2}e^{y^2}$ is convex.

Comment: <slaps forehead>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the Hessian of
$$
(y_2-\gamma y_1)-(y_3-\gamma y_2)e^{x\cdot\beta}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
H
&=\frac{\partial\nabla f}{\partial(\gamma,\beta)}\\[12pt]
&=\frac{\partial\left(-y_1+y_2e^{x\cdot\beta},(\gamma y_2-y_3)xe^{x\cdot\beta}\right)}{\partial(\gamma,\beta)}\\[6pt]
&=\begin{bmatrix}0&y_2x\\[3pt]y_2x'&(\gamma y_2-y_3)x'x\end{bmatrix}e^{x\cdot\beta}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-x\cdot\beta}\begin{bmatrix}u&v\end{bmatrix}H\begin{bmatrix}u\\v'\end{bmatrix}
&=\begin{bmatrix}y_2v\cdot x&\left(y_2u+(\gamma y_2-y_3)v\cdot x\right)x\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}u&v\end{bmatrix}\\
&=y_2uv\cdot x+\left(y_2u+(\gamma y_2-y_3)v\cdot x\right)v\cdot x\\[6pt]
&=2y_2uv\cdot x+(\gamma y_2-y_3)(v\cdot x)^2
\end{align}
$$
If $y_2=0$ and $y_3\le0$, then the Hessian would be positive.